# How to send 3D model files to client using node and/or express?

Tags: node.js, express, three.js

I have files on amazon S3 and would like to send them to the client (logged-in user) when a request is made. I have a working setup for normal text files, but cannot get the same result for 3D models (in `ply` format).

The code that works for text files is:

```js
bucket_name = "..."
key_string = "..."

app.post("/textfile", function(req, res, next){
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        s3.getObject(
          // key_string points to a .txt file on S3
          { Bucket: bucket_name, Key: key_string },
          function (error, data) {
              res.send(data.Body);
          }
      );
});
```

On the client side I have:

```js
fetch('localhost:/textfile', {
                method: "POST",
                header: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
        })
          .then(function(response) {
             return response.text();
           })
          .then(function(res_text) {
                  var string_blob = new Blob( [ res_text], { type: 'text/plain'} );
                  file_object = new File([string_blob ], "filename.txt")
                  // loadFile reads a file object and return a Promise object 
                  // it is provided by another library http://nglviewer.org/ngl/api/class/src/stage/stage.js~Stage.html#instance-method-loadFile
                  loadFile(file_object);
          });
  };
```

However, I cannot get the same result when I try to send a `model.ply` file. I am trying to generate a file object that I can pass to `PLYLoader` something like this:

```js
var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader(); 
// ply_file_object generated similar to the code above (for file_object)
loader.load(ply_file_object);
```

So far, I've tried changing the `"Content-Type"` to either `model/ply`, `application/octet-stream`, `application/octet-binary` but none of them work, and it is driving me crazy. My ideal solution is sending the data to the client without downloading it on the server, as such I haven't tried the `res.sendFile()` functionality yet.

Suggestions, comments and even criticism are most welcome.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, I found this library: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/threejs-ply-loader` which helps to read PLY files. I then do: 

`const plyLoader = new PLYLoader();` 
`const fileArrayBuffer = plyLoader.bufferToArrayBuffer(data.Body);`
`const geo = plyLoader.parse(fileArrayBuffer);`
`res.send({"geo": geometry});`


Hope this helps.